Регулярное выражение для поиска см мм штук шт метров тонн тн
Всем привет.
Необходимо сделать регулярное выражение для поиска:

см мм штук шт метров тонн тн
целые и дробные числа
может быть пробел или нет

Например
tx = 'sldn klds 20шт nsdfnklsd 10,0 кг'
# результат [('20шт', '10,0 кг')]

Заранее благодарен!!!

типа \d+(,\d+)? ?(см|мм|штук|шт|метров|тонн|тн)?

@Akina    re.findall(r'(\d+.?\d+)\s?(кг|см)', tx)   только результат немного другой получается [('20.0', 'см'), ('10', 'кг')]

re.findall(r'(\d+.?\d+\s?+(см|кг|штук|шт|метров|тонн|тн))', tx)  результат [('20.0см', 'см'), ('10 кг', 'кг')]   как только см и кг убрать

import re

tx = 'sldn klds klnflk 20.0см nsdfnklsd 10 кг'
re.findall(r'(\d+\.?\d+\s?+(?:см|кг|штук|шт|метров|тонн|тн))', tx)

# ['20.0см', '10 кг']


Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit].


Необходимо сделать регулярное выражение для поиска

Предложу такой вариант...


const tx = 'sldn klds 20шт nsdfnklsd 10,0 кг'
const r = /\d+(?:\,\d+)?\s*\S+/g
const v = tx.match(r)
console.log(v)



